# Passing c# list to an ASP text field

Tags: c#, list

I was trying to output a single List variable that retrieves data from database via a CodeBehind code to a text field in ASPX:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TBCluster" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
```

C# is used and the code goes something like this:

```
public List<shuffleDataList> pullShuffledData(SqlDataReader rdr)
{
    List<shuffleDataList> callList = new List<shuffleDataList>();      
    if (rdr != null)
    {
         if (rdr.HasRows)
         { 
             while (rdr.Read())
             {   
                 callList.Add(new shuffleDataList()
                 {
                      cluster = rdr.IsDBNull(5) ? null : rdr.GetString(5),
                 });   
             }
         }
         else
         {
             Response.Write("<script>alert('the data is null')</script>");
             return null;
         }
     }
     return callList;
 }
```

The retrieval of cluster field will occur after a user clicks on a particular button and so my passing the variable goes into like the following:

```
protected void shuffle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   getdata();
   TBCluster.Text = new shuffleDataList().cluster;
}
```

However nothing is displayed on the textfield. On the same query, I can display the data on a datagrid view but not on a text field? Any ideas why is this occuring?

Thank you

Comment: What does your second code snippet have to do with the first? They seem completely unrelated / don't call each other.

Comment: the shuffle_Click() is the code behind the button for which should call the data once clicked

Comment: ...but, you're not even calling the function...

Comment: why do you expect cluster to contain anything at all? And when it is null you'll get a runtime exception.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead what do you mean? What should I do with this line: "TBCluster.Text = new shuffleDataList().cluster"?

Comment: @VenkatRenukaPrasad because it outputs something on the datagrid but not on a textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually appear to be calling your function. Also, since a `Text` property is generally a string.. you won't be able to assign a list to it (with any meaningful result). Therefore, I will make a heap of assumptions about your code.. and give you this:

```
var list = pullShuffledData(someReaderHere);

if (list != null)
    TBCluster.Text = string.Join(", ", list.Select(x => x.cluster));
```

Comment: what do you mean by the "x"? Is it a placeholder? Sorry as I am very new in C#.

Comment: To answer that I will direct you here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx

Comment: @vishu This is lamda expression, you can take it as a foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved my issue:

```
            string cluster = string.Empty;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            List<shuffleDataList> list = pullShuffledData(rdr);
            foreach(shuffleDataList item in list)
            {
                cluster = item.cluster;
            }

            TBCluster.Text = cluster;
```

It was supposed to be displayed early on but this gridview seems to be clearing the value of pullShuffledData once assigned

```
         //gridviewShuffle.DataSource =  pullShuffledData(rdr);
            //gridviewShuffle.DataBind();
```

after commenting out, the cluster value finally appeared on text box. thanks